# Avoiding multiple near identical declarations for classes that implement a interface

Tags: c++, class, declaration, dry, class-design

I have a abstract base class called `Command` that acts as an interface for commands that can be put in a queue:

```
class Command
{
public:

    Command(Dependency1& d1, Dependency2& d2);

    //...Irrelevant code removed for simplicity...

private:

    //Implementations do their work in their override of operator()
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};
```

Then I have the declarations for the implementations in a header file:

```
class FooCommand : public Command
{
public:

    using Command::Command;

private:

    void operator()() override; 
};

class BarCommand : public Command
{
public:

    using Command::Command;

private:

    void operator()() override; 
};

class BazCommand : public Command
{  
public:

    using Command::Command;

private:

    void operator()() override; 
};

//...And many more...
```

So now I have a long list of near identical class declarations, only the name differs a bit. What would be the preferred ways to clean this up besides C style macro's?

Comment: Do you need to use inheritance? What about function pointers, lambda expressions, or `std::function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you need to do in your `operator()`.

If you don't need any access to the `Command`'s state, then you could opt to pass a callable to the constructor.  Like here:

```
class CallCommand : public Command { 
    std::function<void()> f;
public:
    CallCommand(Dependency1& d1, Dependency2& d2, std::function<void()> f) : Command(d1,d2), f(f) {
    }
private:
    void operator()() override { f(); }
};
```

You could then call it by providing either a free function, a lambda, or any `std::function` object.  For example:

```
CallCommand c(d1,d2, [](){ cout<<"Hello world"<<endl;});
```

But if you need to access the class context, then I'm affraid there's no way around a real overriding like you did (and macro is an awful work around for the boilerplate code).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is similar to what has been answered by [Cristophe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55449593/1112010) but does not use inheritance.

You probably don't need inheritance. Instead, you could use `std::function` or `lambda` expressions. See, for example:

```
class Command
{
private:
  std::function<void()> f;
public:
  Command(Dependency1& d1, Dependency2& d2, std::function<void()> f): d1(d1), d2(d2), f(f) {}

  void operator()() {
    f();
  }
};
```

You could then create objects of `Command` and use them wherever in a `queue` or `vector` as desired.

```
Command call1(0, 0, []() {
  std::cout << "call1" << std::endl;
});
Command call2(0, 0, []() {
  std::cout << "call2" << std::endl;
});
std::vector<Command> v;
v.emplace_back(call1);
v.emplace_back(call2);
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
  v[i]();
}
```

Pre `c++11`, you can avoid inheritance by creating **function pointers** to each function and pass those pointers to the `Command` constructor.